# How to create multiple website using one IP adress (apache2)

Tags: apache, ubuntu, apache2, web-hosting, ubuntu-server

I installed ubuntu server 16.10 on VirtualBox recently in order to host a website on it thanks to apache2.
I followed some tutorials to do it, but here's the issue :  it doesn't work :/

I mean, when I use ifconfig, I get the following IP : 10.41.175.36
If I type this IP in the URL, I get the default html page for apache. So this is good, I guess, I'm able to access this webpage from any devices if they're connected to the same wifi.

Now I want to create 2 websites on my ubuntu server, I created one index.html in /var/www/site1 and one in /var/www/site2, I configured the .conf in /etc/apache2/sites-available for the 2 websites, I restard the apache2 and enabled the websites.

Now, I tried to enter the domain name I gave them but It tells me that the URL isn't known.

I edited the /etc/hosts to change domain name and it doesn't work.

So do you have a tip or a tutorial in order to create the websites ?
I hope I was clear, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should check out VirtualHosts on Apache2. https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer !